# Ghostscript renders ugly text

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, text-rendering

I'm trying to add the capability to render LaTeX equations to a project I'm working on. To do so, I use XeLaTeX to create a PDF file, which I then render to a (transparent) 96dpi-PNG using Ghostscript.

I'd like to have the rendered LaTeX blend in with the rest of the text (which is rendered using standard .NET GDI+ methods, but that's off-topic), but I can't get a reliably "good" text rendering: the output always looks somehow blurry or otherwise "bad".

Example:

[image: Comparison]

From left to right, the same (small) PDF rendered at 96dpi with Ghostscript, Photoshop, and TexWorks (which I understand uses Ghostscript internally).

The command I use to run Ghostscript is the following:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/gs/gs9.09/bin/gswin32c.exe" \
      -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT \
      -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=1 -dGridFitTT=2 \
       "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 \
      -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r96" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 \
      -sOutputFile="output.png" "input.pdf"
```

(which I actually pretty much copied from the command ImageMagick calls when converting a PDF file, but that's another story). I tried changing any of the relevant options (dAlignToPixels=0, dGridFitTT=0/1/2, dTextAlphaBits=2/4 [or without this parameter altogether]) and I even tried to render the PDF to 4 times the resolution and then downscale it, without any noticeable improvement.

Yet, I'm sure there must be some way of decently rendering the PDF with Ghostscript (since TexWorks does), although I'm unable to find it.

Any hint? The PDF is [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6zlv93dr95j934/Test.pdf?dl=0).

Comment: I am having the same problem. Text rendering quality of ghostscript is dreadful compared to mupdf or pdfium. And so far the answers haven't been helpful at all...

Answer (score 2):

You could try to render your PDF at a higher resolution. 96dpi just isn't enough for text with 11 pt size.

If you use 192dpi and then scale the display of the resulting image to 50% (wherever you use the PNG), these parts should still appear in the same size as befor, but with a higher resolution. What used to be a 4x7 pixels *'s'* should now be a 8x14 pixels *'s'*...

---

### Update

Ok, since my explanation seems to have been not comprehendible enough for the OP, here's the deal.

1. Generate a PDF file containing the word "Test", using Ghostscript. In my case, it is Ghostscript v9.10:

   ```
   gs                       \
    -o test.pdf             \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite       \
    -g230x100               \
    -c "/Helvetica findfont \
        11 scalefont        \
        setfont             \
        1 1 moveto          \
        (Test) show         \
        showpage"
   ```
2. From this PDF, generate 6 different images depicting the word "Test", using 6 different resolutions. The `gs` is still Ghostscript v9.10 (to be checked with `gs -version`):

   ```
   for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do      \
       gs                        \
        -o t$(( ${i} * 96 )).png \
        -r$(( ${i} * 96 ))       \
        -sDEVICE=pngalpha        \
        -dAlignToPixels=1        \
        -dGridFitTT=2            \
        -dTextAlphaBits=4        \
        -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4    \
         t.pdf ;                 \
   done
   ```

   This will create the following PNGs, as confirmed by ImageMagick's `identify` command:

   ```
   identify -format "%f :   %Wx%H pixels  --  %b filesize\n" t[1-9]*.png
     t96.png :   31x13 pixels  --     475B filesize
    t192.png :   61x27 pixels  --     774B filesize
    t288.png :   92x40 pixels  --    1.1KB filesize
    t384.png :  123x53 pixels  --   1.43KB filesize
    t480.png :  153x67 pixels  --   1.76KB filesize
    t576.png :  184x80 pixels  --   2.01KB filesize
   ```
3. Create a sample LaTeX document and embed the different images side by side and/or line by line. Here is my sample code:

   ```
   \begin{document}
   Test
   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t96.png}
   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t96.png}
   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t192.png}
   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t288.png}
   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t384.png}
   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t480.png}
   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t576.png}
   Test\\

   {}

   Test <== real text

   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t96.png}  <-- 96 dpi figure

   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t192.png} <-- 192 dpi figure

   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t288.png} <-- 288 dpi figure

   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t384.png} <-- 384 dpi figure

   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t480.png} <-- 480 dpi figure

   \includegraphics[height=7.5pt]{t576.png} <-- 576 dpi figure

   Test <== real text
   \end{document}
   ```
4. Here is a screenshot (at 400% zoom) from the PDF created via LuaLaTeX from the above LaTeX code:

   [image: Screenshot from resulting PDF page]

   The line with the 8 "Test" words has actual text only in the first and the last word. The 6 words in between are images with 96, 96, 192, 288, 384, 480 and 576 dpi.

I hope you can see now clearly how scaling up your image generation to a higher resolution will result in better quality for your final PDF if you include the higher resolution images into your LaTeX code...

Comment: "I even tried to render the PDF to 4 times the resolution and then downscale it, without any noticeable improvement"...

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough: "I even tried to render the PDF to 4 times the resolution and then downscale it, without any noticeable improvement" means that **I had indeed already tried to do exactly what you suggested**, and I didn't get any noticeable improvements. Furthermore, I fail to see how the latex document example is relevant to the matter... Yet it is interesting that your gs output is so much better than mine, even though we are using mostly the same command to render, and how that may be possible is exactly my original question...

Comment: @arklumpus: So, you *"fail to see how the latex document example is relevant to the matter"*??? I put my code snippets up in the interest and for the benefit of other visitors to this page, who then can reproduce my exact results. If it was only for you and your nice behaviour, I wouldn't answer any more...

Comment: Fine, I see you don't get my point, so let's end it all up here.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle thanks for including the LaTeX document in your answer! This made it so much easier to verify your answer for myself, compare your results against mine, make sure it still applies for today's version of GS, and just generally take one more variable out of the equation when testing/comparing this kind of stuff. Yay for complete, self-contained answers!

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering text at 11 points, at 96 dpi, that works out to about 14 pixels in height which, frankly, is not a lot (and in my output the 's' is 7 pixels high by 4 wide). Looking at your output all 3 look 'blurry' and the Photoshop output looks overly bold in the capital T.

If you don't want it blurred, then don't set TextAlphaBits, or don't set it to such a high value.

I'd also suggest using the current release (9.15).

Comment: I agree that all three might look a bit blurry, but you can see that the text rendered by Photoshop or TeXWorks looks way better than the obtained by using only GhostScript... Photoshop may use a different rendering engine altogether, but TeXWorks should use Ghostscript, thus (I think) it should be possible to get a similar output from GhostScript itself.